# How to connect css and javascript in a .jsp file

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-data-jpa

I am having trouble connecting an external css and javascript file to its jsp.

I tried doing the WebConfig as I read on google but I realised that my jsp files' path are done via `application.properties` so when it ran it override the application.properties and the .jsp could not be found. I deleted the WebConfig and stuck with the `application.properties` and tried to add a filepath for css

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/ 
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp  
spring.web.resources.statstaticic-locations=classpath:/static/,classpath:/public/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/META-INF/resources/
```

These made the JSP run but it could not read the css.

**File Path for JSP:**
src-> main -> webapp-> home.jsp

**home.jsp:**

```
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="c:url value='/css/home.css' />">     
<title>Project One</title> </head> <body>
```

**File Path for CSS:**
src-> main-> resources-> static-> css-> home.css

I am not sure if this matters but these are the dependencies I am using (gradle):

```
dependencies {

   implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
   developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
   testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
  runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'



   runtimeOnly 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:10.1.9' //jsp
   runtimeOnly 'org.glassfish.web:jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl:3.0.0'  //helpful jsp tags
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not configured static resources or tried to configure it but have a wrong property name.

```
spring.web.resources.statstaticic-locations=classpath:/static/,classpath:/public/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/META-INF/resources/
```

See chapter 27:
[**Developing web applications**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.8.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#:%7E:text=By%20default%20Spring%20Boot%20will,the%20root%20of%20the%20ServletContext%20.)

> By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a directory called `/static` (or `/public` or `/resources` or `/META-INF/resources` ) in the classpath or from the root of the `ServletContext`.